# How to format param-signature for a JSNI method with more than 1 parameter?

Tags: gwt, jsni

I am using GWT and have a Java method with a signature that requires a string and a boolean parameter, like this:

```
private void myMethod(String s, Boolean b) {}
```

I have a JSNI method that exposes this Java method after compilation:

```
public class myClass {
    public native void exportMyMethod(myClass c)/*-{
        $wnd.myMethod = $entry(function(s, b) {
            c.@com.path.to.myClass::myMethod(Ljava/lang/String;Z);
        });
    }-*/;
}
```

For the life of me, I cannot figure out how to properly format the param-signature when there's more than 1 parameter.

I've read the [GWT documentation regarding how to do this](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsJSNI.html#methods-fields). I've also read where that document [directs me to how to properly refer to the JNI Type](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/jni/spec/types.html#wp16432). But I cannot seem to find an example of how to format the signature when using more than 1 parameter. It seems like it should be easy.

So, how do I format my param-signature correctly? I've tried:

- c.@com.path.to.myClass::myMethod(Ljava/lang/String;Z);
- c.@com.path.to.myClass::myMethod(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Boolean;);
- c.@com.path.to.myClass::myMethod(Ljava/lang/StringLjava/lang/Boolean;);
- c.@com.path.to.myClass::myMethod(Ljava/lang/String;,Ljava/lang/Boolean;);

Every different permutation that I've tried has resulted in the same error.

"Referencing method 'com.path.to.myClass.myMethod(Ljava/lang/String;Z)/' unable to resolve method."

Comment: It may be worth noting that I've changed the method signature to only use a single parameter and everything runs fine. It just can't seem to map to my Java method with more than 1 parameter defined. At least, not until I figure out how to properly format them. :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Javascript, unlike Java, you can actually pass a method as if it were a variable - you can reassign it, assign it to a variable, etc. That means that for JSNI references to work, we need to have a way not only to call them, but to reference them.

The standard JSNI pattern then is `instance.@path.to.Class::method(arg;types;)(actual, params)`

In your case, this line

```
c.@com.path.to.myClass::myMethod(Ljava/lang/String;Z);
```

should be changed to something like this

```
c.@com.path.to.myClass::myMethod(Ljava/lang/String;Z)(s, b);
```

Please note however that `Z` refers to `boolean`, not `Boolean`, so the current code in your question is inconsistent. If only one method exists with a particular name, you can omit the types and just pass `*`:

```
c.@com.path.to.myClass::myMethod(*)(s, b);
```

Comment: Thank you! It was a matter of me mixing up a Boolean and a boolean.

Answer (score 2):

A class reference starts with an `L` and ends with a `;`, and argument types aren't separated; so only the first two signatures are well-formed:

- `c.@com.path.to.myClass::myMethod(Ljava/lang/String;Z);`
- `c.@com.path.to.myClass::myMethod(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Boolean;);`

The first one takes a `boolean`, the second a `java.lang.Boolean`.